# Zero-knowledge proof for $P \ne NP$?

Tags: computational-complexity, proof-complexity

In computational complexity, $P \ne NP$ is a widely believed conjecture. Suppose that someone discovered a proof for it. He wants to publish a proof that he correctly proved the conjecture. I am aware that NP-complete problems have [Zero-knowledge proofs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-knowledge_proof). Assuming $P \ne NP$, can we have Zero-knowledge proof (or morally equivalent one) for  $P \ne NP$?

Comment: If you could produce a [Homeomorphic encryption scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homomorphic_encryption) for logical deduction then you could give the 'plaintext' and encrypted versions of your axioms (anyone can confirm that they encrypt to the appropriate form), give all of the 'encrypted' deduction steps, and then give the plaintext and encrypted versions of the final statement (which again can be confirmed without access to the middle steps).

Answer (score 4):

If your friend is willing to part with an upper bound $B$ on the length of the proof in some formal system, then you can

1. Take a computer program which verifies proofs in that formal
   system, which (presumably) runs in polynomial time
2. Convert it into a circuit which takes $B$ bits as input and outputs True if it is a valid proof of $P \neq NP$ and False otherwise.
3. Reduce CircuitSat to the existence of a Hamiltonian cycle using the NP-completeness of Hamiltonian cycles, and find the Hamiltonian cycle corresponding to the proof.
4. Use the zero knowledge proof scheme for Hamiltonian cycles.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, it does not really make sense to talk about zero-knowledge proofs for a single statement such as $P\ne NP$.  You really should be asking about whether there is a zero-knowledge proof for a *computational problem*, such as: "Given a statement $S$ in the first-order language of set theory, and a positive integer $n$, does there exist a ZFC-proof of $S$ of length at most $n$?"

With this reformulation, you have already partially answered your own question, by noting that there is a standard theorem about the existence of zero-knowledge proofs for any $NP$-complete language. However, there are two caveats to be aware of in that standard theorem. The first caveat is that it assumes the existence of a one-way function, which is a stronger assumption than $P\ne NP$. So if you only have the hypothesis $P\ne NP$ available to you, then that's not quite good enough.  The second caveat is that the usual proof relies on a *commitment scheme*, which has two parts to it, the *binding* part and the *hiding* part.  Ideally we'd like both parts to be statistically secure and not just computationally secure, but it turns out that it is impossible for both parts to be statistically secure unless the polynomial hierarchy collapses to the second level (Fortnow, "The complexity of perfect zero knowledge").  So if you want the strongest possible form of zero knowledge, then the answer to your question is likely no.

Comment: So, if P=NP ( way-way functions doesn't exist) then we can't have zero-knowledge proof for P=NP.

Comment: @MohammadAl-Turkistany Again, you should get out of the bad habit of talking about zero-knowledge proofs for single statements such as P = NP. But in any case, if P = NP, then zero-knowledge proofs as usually conceived are not so interesting. Everyone can then compute their own proofs of major theorems, so what are you doing trying to "keep secret" something that is public knowledge anyway? Now, there are ways of making sense of zero-knowledge proofs even in this scenario, but it's subtle, and beyond the scope of this comment.

Answer (score 1):

This is just a long comment, but it probably depends on the actual structure of the proof.

Imagine some Ramsey-theoretical question, and you have proved that all graphs with property P are Hamiltonian. One zero-knowledge proof would be your friend supplying you with a graph with property P, and you produce a Hamiltonian cycle in it.
But, proving that something is Hamiltonian is not the same as being able to (efficiently) producing the Hamiltonian cycle, so you are stuck.

One can imagine a probabilistic type proof, showing that the expected number of 'obstructions' to $P=NP$ is positive, but this is not at all the same as being able to produce such obstructions concretely (which is perhaps what a zero-knowledge proof would be).

However, there are certainly many ways to give zero-knowledge proofs of $P=NP$,
perhaps the easiest one is to break some encryption scheme and get rich.

Also, [this paper](https://www2.karlin.mff.cuni.cz/%7Ekrajicek/ri5svetu.pdf) seems very much related.